# How to balance a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I'm practicing binary tree problems on LeetCode and I'm struggling at the moment with balancing a binary search tree.  I feel as if I got the logic of it, but I'm getting weird errors when using pointers.

```
    /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    void inOrder(TreeNode* root, vector<int> bst)
    {
        if (root != NULL)
        {
            inOrder(root->left, bst);
            bst.push_back(root->val);
            inOrder(root->right, bst);
        }
    }
    
    
    TreeNode* Insert(TreeNode* bt, int median)
    {
        if (bt == NULL)
        {
            return new TreeNode(median);
        }
        
        if (median > bt->val)
        {
            bt->right = Insert(bt->right, median);
        }
        else
        {
            bt->left = Insert(bt->left, median);
        }
        
        return bt;
     }
        
        
    
    TreeNode* balanceBST(TreeNode* root) {
        
        vector<int> sortedBST;
        inOrder(root, sortedBST);
        int size = sortedBST.size();
        TreeNode* balancedBST;
        int mid;
        
        while (size != 0)
        {
            if (size % 2 == 1 || size % 2 == 0)
                mid = size/2;
            
            if (balancedBST == NULL)
            {
                balancedBST = new TreeNode(sortedBST[mid]);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode* node = Insert(balancedBST, sortedBST[mid]);
            }
            
            sortedBST.erase(sortedBST.begin() + mid);
            --size;
        }
        
        return balancedBST;
    }
};
```

The error I received was this:

> > =================================================================
> > ==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffc15eb8028 at pc 0x000000374488 bp 0x7ffc15eb7dd0 sp
> > 0x7ffc15eb7dc8 READ of size 8 at 0x7ffc15eb8028 thread T0
> > #5 0x7fac728370b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2) Address 0x7ffc15eb8028 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 72
> > in frame   This frame has 1 object(s):
> > [32, 112) 'q' <== Memory access at offset 72 is inside this variable HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some
> > custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
> > (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)

Comment: This is wrong: `void inOrder(TreeNode* root, vector<int> bst)`  You are making a copy of the vector and then updating the data it points to.  But the size and capacity won't be updated so the resulting vector will be wrong.

Comment: Also, in balanceBST you do this: `TreeNode* balancedBST;` and then this: `if (balancedBST == NULL)` but balancedBST has NO value because you didn't initialize it.  That means anything could happen.

Comment: you still have a bit of logic to fix, but like @JerryJeremiah said, change to ```void inOrder(TreeNode* root, std::vector<int>& bst)``` and ```TreeNode* balancedBST = NULL;```

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing that out.  I see the logic is incorrect now, but now I don't have to worry about pointer errors thank you.

Comment: Here is a working example with just those two changes: https://onlinegdb.com/H1toB0kp4

Comment: Amazing that it runs at all. The `TreeNode`  definition appears to be commented out.

Comment: @user4581301 I have never been there but I think the website must compile your "Solution" class with a bunch of code you aren't allowed to change (like the definition of the TreeNode and the main function) so the user doesn't supply these.  This code must be a copy and paste of the user's code and not an MVCE since there is also no main function.